# "Attempt to compare number with nil" error

Tags: lua, roblox

When I touch the winpad (part that will trigger the code above), it will keep saying error

> ServerScriptService.Pads:342: attempt to compare number < nil

Line 342 is

```
    if Times < minTime and Timem < 1 and kicks == true and #Boosts == 0 then
```

Here is some context around line 342

```
    local BadgeIDValue = Winpad.KitFolder.Value:FindFirstChild("BadgeID")
    local BadgeID = 0
    if BadgeIDValue then BadgeID = BadgeIDValue.Value end
    local TowerNameValue = Winpad.KitFolder.Value:FindFirstChild("ProperName")
    local TowerName = "Unknown"
    if TowerNameValue then TowerName = TowerNameValue.Value end
    local difficulty = Winpad:GetAttribute("Difficulty")
    local diffcolor = DifficultyDictionaryColors[difficulty]
    local nicelevel = Winpad:GetAttribute("NiceLevel")
    local isSC = Winpad:GetAttribute("isSC")
    local winroom = Winpad:GetAttribute("Winroom")
    local minTime = Winpad:GetAttribute("MinimalTime")
    local CPsReq = Winpad:GetAttribute("CPsRequired")
    local Time:string,Boosts:table<string>? = GetTimerRemote:InvokeClient(Player)
    local checks = ServerStorage:FindFirstChild(Player.Name)
    local towerac = v.Name
    local Times = tonumber(string.sub(Time, 4, 5))
    local Timem = tonumber(string.sub(Time, 1, 2))
    local kicks = script.Switches.KicksEnabled.Value
    if Times < minTime and Timem < 1 and kicks == true and #Boosts == 0 then
        Kick(Player, Time, TowerName, difficulty, Boosts, script.KickReasons.TooEarly.Value) return
    end
    if checks and CPsFound and kicks == true and #Boosts == 0 then
        for i, v in pairs(checks:GetChildren()) do
            if checks:FindFirstChild(towerac.."_"..i) then
                CPCount = CPCount + 1
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Which line is 342? currently i would suggest printing `Times` and `Timem` and see if either is `nil` chances are that one, or both, of those is your problem. it is probably due to how your parsing the `Time` value.

Comment: “ if Times < minTime and Timem < 1 and kicks == true and #Boosts == 0 then” is the error line

Comment: Yeah right before that line add `print(Time, Timem, Times)` the result of that print should give you what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok cool, I will check it tomorrow then

Answer (score 0):

The `minTime` attribute may not exist check the Winpad attributes again